# performance issue with sched_domain on centOS 7.9?

Tags: performance, cpu, centos7, sched

I have 2 servers with exactly same specific.

when I check the `sysctl -a`

one server has just one group as below by core

```
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_factor = 32
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_idx = 2
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 1
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.flags = 559
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.idle_idx = 0
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.imbalance_pct = 117
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 64
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 4278
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 32
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.name = MC
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
 kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.wake_idx = 0
```

but another server has 3 of them like below

```
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_factor = 32
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.busy_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.cache_nice_tries = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.flags = 687
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.forkexec_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.idle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.imbalance_pct = 110
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_interval = 4
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.max_newidle_lb_cost = 3459
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.min_interval = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.name = SMT
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.newidle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain0.wake_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.busy_factor = 32
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.busy_idx = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.cache_nice_tries = 1
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.flags = 4655
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.forkexec_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.idle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.imbalance_pct = 117
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.max_interval = 64
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.max_newidle_lb_cost = 16233
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.min_interval = 32
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.name = MC
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.newidle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain1.wake_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.busy_factor = 32
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.busy_idx = 3
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.cache_nice_tries = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.flags = 25647
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.forkexec_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.idle_idx = 2
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.imbalance_pct = 125
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.max_interval = 128
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.max_newidle_lb_cost = 18225
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.min_interval = 64
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.name = NUMA
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.newidle_idx = 0
kernel.sched_domain.cpu0.domain2.wake_idx = 0
```

I suspect that this difference make low performance with first server.

so i would like to know

1. how to config to have multiple domain? not only MC.
2. any possibility it makes performance difference?

Thanks in advance.

tried config BIOS, ILO...
but until now, no luck